# Disable Swipe for position in RecyclerView using ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview 22.2.0 and the helper class ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback to enable *swipe-to-dismiss* option to my list. But as I have a type of header on it, I need to disable the swipe behavior for the first position of the adapter. As **RecyclerView.Adapter** doesn't have a **isEnabled()** method, I tried to disable the view interaction through the methods **isEnabled()** and **isFocusable()** in the ViewHolder creation itself, but had no success. I tried to adjust the swipe threshold to a full value, like **0f** ot **1f** in the SimpleCallback's method **getSwipeThreshold()**, but no success too.

Some fragments of my code to help you to help me.

**My Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    //... initialization
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                          RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public float getSwipeThreshold(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            if (viewHolder instanceof CartAdapter.MyViewHolder) return 1f;
            return super.getSwipeThreshold(viewHolder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {

        }
    };

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

And I have a common adapter with *two* view types. In the *ViewHolder* that I want to disable swiping, I did:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewGroup mContainer;

    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setFocusable(false);
        v.setEnabled(false);
        mContainer = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.container);      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 256, accepted):

After playing a bit, I managed that **SimpleCallback** has a method called **getSwipeDirs()**. As I have a specific ViewHolder for the *not swipable* position, I can make use of **instanceof** to avoid the swipe. If that's not your case, you can perform this control using the position of ViewHolder in the Adapter.

**Java**

```
@Override
public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    if (viewHolder instanceof CartAdapter.MyViewHolder) return 0;
    return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
override fun getSwipeDirs (recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
    if (viewHolder is CartAdapter.MyViewHolder) return 0
    return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder)
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Especially when this method does not appear on the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html)...

Comment: @ptitvinou it's present on `SimpleCallback` http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback.html

Comment: Worth mentioning: if You want just to allow for one direction on certain items then use 
`return position == 0 ? ItemTouchHelper.LEFT : super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);` - this one i.e. allow only for left swipes.

Comment: Perfect. Working like a charm

Comment: How does this work? What do I do if I want to disable swiping right for example?

Comment: You're the best.

Comment: How to prevent swipe up to a specific level? Like I want to swipe a cell to left up to its center and then stop moving further left. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I've added the Kotlin version.

Comment: @RafaelToledo please include jeand'arme's comment in your answer. It is really simple and was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 72):

If someone is using **ItemTouchHelper.Callback**. Then You can remove any related flags in **getMovementFlags(..)** function.

```
@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
    int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
}
```

Here instead of **dragFlags** and **swipeFlags** You can pass 0 to disable corresponding feature.

**ItemTouchHelper.START** means swiping left to right in case of left to right locale (LTR application Support), but the other way around in a right to left locale (RTL application Support).
**ItemTouchHelper.END** means swiping in the opposite direction of `START`.

so you can remove any flag according to your requirements.

Comment: Thank !, I use code:     @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN; // movements drag
        return makeFlag( ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG , dragFlags); // as parameter, action drag and flags drag
    }

Comment: This is the preferred answer if (unlike OP) you are extending `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` directly.

Answer (score 28):

Here's a simple way to do this that only depends upon the position of the item being swiped:

```
@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    int dragFlags = 0; // whatever your dragFlags need to be
    int swipeFlags = createSwipeFlags(position)

    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
}

private int createSwipeFlags(int position) {
  return position == 0 ? 0 : ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
}
```

This should also work if you're using `SimpleCallback`:

```
@Override
public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    return createSwipeFlags(position);
}

private int createSwipeFlags(int position) {
  return position == 0 ? 0 : super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
}
```

If you want to disable swiping conditional upon the data in the item, use the `position` value to get data from the adapter for the item being swiped and disable accordingly.

If you already have specific holder types which need to not swipe, the accepted answer will work. However, creating holder types as a proxy for position is a kludge and should be avoided.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few ways to go about this, but if you only have one ViewHolder, but more than one layout you can take this approach.

Override the getItemViewType and give it some logic as to determine view type based on position or type of data in object (I have a getType function in my object)

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return data.get(position).getType;
}
```

Return proper layout in onCreateView based on ViewType (Make sure to pass view type to ViewHolder class.

```
@Override
public AppListItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    mContext = parent.getContext();

    if (viewType == 0){
        return new AppListItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false), viewType);
    else
        return new AppListItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false), viewType);
    }
}
```

Get the content views of the different layouts based on view type
    public static class AppListItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

```
    public AppListItemHolder (View v, int viewType) {
        super(v);

        if (viewType == 0)
            ... get your views contents
        else
            ... get other views contents
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your ItemTouchHelper change actions based on ViewType. For me this disables swiping of a RecyclerView section header

```
@Override
public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == 1) return 0;
        return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea but getItemViewType is final

Answer (score 5):

First in recyclerView at onCreateViewHolder method, set tag for each viewHolder type, like below code:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    if(ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL == viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.deposite_card_view, viewGroup, false);
        ItemViewHolder holder = new ItemViewHolder(context, v);
        holder.itemView.setTag("normal");
        return holder;
    } else {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_header, viewGroup, false);
        HeaderViewHolder holder = new HeaderViewHolder(context, v);
        holder.itemView.setTag("header");
        return holder;
    }
}
```

then in ItemTouchHelper.Callback implementation, update getMovementFlags method, like below:

```
public class SwipeController extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    if("normal".equalsIgnoreCase((String) viewHolder.itemView.getTag())) {
        return makeMovementFlags(0, LEFT | RIGHT);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

at end attach to recyclerView:

```
final SwipeController swipeController = new SwipeController();

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(swipeController);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the @Rafael Toledo answer, If you want to remove the specific swipe gesture like LEFT swipe or RIGHT swipe based on position or type of data in object in Adapter, then you can do like this.

```
@Override
  public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
       {
          int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
          ConversationDataModel conversationModel = null;
          conversationModel = mHomeAdapter.getItems().get(position);
          boolean activeChat = true;
          if(conversationModel!=null && !conversationModel.isActive())
           {
             activeChat = false;
           }
  return activeChat ? super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder): ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
        }
```

Here in my case, In my Recyclerview I am loading the chat conversations and it have RIGHT (for ARCHIVE) & LEFT ( for EXIT) swipe gestures on each item. But in case if the conversation is not active, then I need to disable the RIGHT swipe for the specific item in the Recycler view.

So I am checking for the `activeChat` and accordingly and disabled the RIGHT swipe.

Comment: this is the closest to my final solution combined with @M.Kouchi's tag approach. The only thing had to change was instead of returning ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT I returned ACTION_STATE_IDLE.

Answer (score 3):

It can be disabled using `ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE`

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
    ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, //drag directions
    ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE //swipe directions
)
```

```
val touchHelperCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {
    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        (recyclerView.adapter as MyAdapter).onItemMove(viewHolder.adapterPosition, target.adapterPosition)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        return
    }

}
val touchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(touchHelperCallback)
touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewX)
```