# Dettach SwipeListener from Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe, gesture, itemtouchhelper

I've got a simple left/right swipe listener for my `RecyclerView`, so I created the following function in my fragment.

```
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper;
public void setDeleteUpdateSwipeListener() {
      ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
           //do stuff
           Log.e("i still", "get called");
        }


    };

    itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvListDriver);
}
```

If the user clicks on an item for longer period of time, I don't want to allow any wipes, so I did this in my adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DriverListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = holder;
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
          
            drListFrag.setNoSwipeListener();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

And the corresponding function in my fragment:

```
public void setNoSwipeListener() {
    itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(null);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(null);
}
```

However, swipes still are happening and the trace `Log.e` also gets called. I made sure that the function `noSwipe` gets called. I also tried other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713121/disable-swipe-for-position-in-recyclerview-using-itemtouchhelper-simplecallback) but none of them work for me.

May the issue be cause I don't have the `swipelistener` in my `RecycerViewAddapter` but rather in my Fragment/RecycerView object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` and override [`isItemViewSwipeEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper.Callback#isitemviewswipeenabled) method.

The return value of this method determines whether the swipe is enabled or not. If `true` then it's enabled.

So, you can have a local boolean field in the customized `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` with a setter, and toggle its value to `false` within `setNoSwipeListener()`

`isItemViewSwipeEnabled()` should return this local field

And when the touch event is over, then reset this boolean to `true`:

```
holder.listItem.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // Reset the boolean to true
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```java
public void setNoSwipeListener() {
    // itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(null);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(null);
}
```

Comment: I also tried it before. For some reason it only works in the setDeleteUpdateSwipeListener() function. If I put the code in the setNoSwipeListener() function it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure I should see the full code. Are you sure your long click is handled. Are you sure you are referencing the correct `itemTouchHelper` and` drListFrag` instance?

Comment: yes I am, I always traces the call that are made. I enter the onlonglistener event and also the function where i remove the slider listener (in theory). Idc, maybe I need some fresh air and try it later to see where the issue might be